# Resolution refutation for a set of clauses

Tags: logic

Give a resolution refutation for the following clauses:

\begin{align*}
&{c_1}:\{ \neg p \vee \neg r \vee s\}    &&{c_4}:\{ p \vee \neg q\} \\
&{c_2}:\{ \neg r \vee \neg s\}           &&{c_5}:\{ \neg p \vee r \vee \neg s\} \\
&{c_3}:\{ p \vee q\}                     &&{c_6}:\{ r \vee s\}         
\end{align*}

**My work:**

\begin{align*}
  &1. && \{ \neg p \vee \neg r \vee s\}  && {c_1}\\
  &2. && \{ \neg r \vee \neg s\}  && {c_2} \\
  &3. && \{ \neg p \vee \neg r\}  && 1,\,2 \\
  &4. && \{ p \vee q\}  && {c_3} \\
  &5. && \{ \neg r \vee q\}  && 3,\,4 \\
  &6. && \{ p \vee \neg q\}  && {c_4} \\
  &7. && \{ p \vee \neg r\}  && 5,\,6 \\
  &8. && \{ \neg p \vee r \vee \neg s\}  && {c_5} \\
  &9. && \{ \neg s\}  && 7,\,8 \\
  &10. && \{ r \vee s\}  && {c_6} \\
  &11. && \{ r\}  && 9,\,10 \\
\end{align*}

I did not get at the end an empty set $\{ \} $ (like illustrated in most examples i saw), instead i got $r$. What does it mean? Should i always get an empty set at the end if not what is the meaning of last clause in the resolution refutation table/tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of clauses is *unsatisfiable*; thus we have to derive the enpty clause:

1. $c_3,c_4$ : $ p $
2. $c_1,c_2$ : $\lnot p \lor \lnot r$
3. $c_5,c_6$ : $\lnot p \lor r$
4. $2,3$ : $\lnot p$

> 5. $1,4$ : $\{ \quad \}$.

---

> "Should i always get an empty set at the end" ?

NO; only if the set of clauses is *inconsistent*, i.e. *unsatisfiable*.

---

The [Resolution proof procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) needs that:

> The resolution rule is applied to **all possible pairs of clauses that contain complementary literals**. After each application of the resolution rule, the resulting sentence is simplified by removing repeated literals. If the sentence contains complementary literals, it is discarded (as a tautology). If not, and if it is not yet present in the clause set, it is added to it, and is considered for further resolution inferences.

Comment: How do you know that the set of clauses if unsatisfiable if the last clause i derived is not empty? So we can manipulate the order of clauses in order to try to get an empty set in the end? And if we tried all orders and the last set is not empty then we conclude that this set of clauses is satisfiable?

Comment: @user_777 - two ways: apply correctly the resolution procedure **and** check with e.g. truth table.

Comment: well i was using this pattern - http://i.imgur.com/GNQBIk7.png and now its hard to understand the logic in which order we should "join" two clauses to get a new one...

Comment: @user_777 - the resolution procedure is designed for computers; thus, the rule is simply: **all** pairs of clauses wit complementary literals. The result must be added to the set of clauses and no clauses removed.

Comment: With a "human computer"... use insight.